# \penalty Not Having Effect

Tags: page-breaking, penalty

I am trying to suppress page breaks following a minor heading that I've defined.  However, the penalty does not seem to have any effect, no matter where I place it.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\gennotes{%
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    {\Large\scshape\noindent Notes}%
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage[paperheight=3.5in,paperwidth=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\sloppy\noindent
So I really want to have both the indent be surpressed on
the next line \emph{and} the page break penalty be applied.
However, this does not seem to work when I combine the two.
I have made my page quite small here to demonstrate the
problem:

\gennotes

And what now?  Will the indent be surpressed?  Will the page
penalty be applied?  Who can tell?  I certainly can't; all I
know is that it never seems to work the way that I want to,
no matter how much meaningless faff I type into this minimal
example.
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Page1]
[image: Page2]

I have tried putting `\penalty10000` everywhere that makes sense to me, and none of it seems to have any effect.  Where does it belong to prevent a page break after the "Notes" heading but before the text following it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\gennotes{%
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    {\Large\scshape\noindent Notes}%
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage[paperheight=3.5in,paperwidth=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\sloppy\noindent
So I really want to have both the indent be surpressed on
the next line \emph{and} the page break penalty be applied.
However, this does not seem to work when I combine the two.
I have made my page quite small here to demonstrate the
problem:

\gennotes

And what now?  Will the indent be surpressed?  Will the page
penalty be applied?  Who can tell?  I certainly can't; all I
know is that it never seems to work the way that I want to,
no matter how much meaningless faff I type into this minimal
example.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This just adds `\nobreak` (`\penalty10000`) immediately before the skip after the heading.

Comment: Ah, so it's the `\par` that makes the difference (I'd put `\penalty10000` there without success).  I'm going to have to give this a good think to see why that changes things.  Thank you!

Comment: @dgoodmaniii if you put `\nobreak` in horizontal mode it prevents a line break not a page break,